# Selection does not work if "too exact"

Tags: html, d3.js

consider the following minimal example:

```
<p>
    <ol id="First list">
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>bar</li>
    </ol>
    <ol id="Second list">
        <li>baz</li>
    </ol>
</p>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    sel = d3.selectAll("ol")

    console.log(sel)
</script>
```

This works nicely: The selection contains one group which in turn has two elements (the two  elements).

But if I change the selection to

```
sel = d3.select("p").selectAll("ol")
```

which looks "more exact" to me as it uses the more accurate address, the selection returns one group which is empty (that is obviously wrong).

What's the reason for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the MDN documentation regarding a `p` element:

> The start tag is required. The end tag may be omitted if the `<p>`
>   element is immediately followed by an `<address>, <article>, <aside>,
>   <blockquote>, <div>, <dl>, <fieldset>, <footer>, <form>, <h1>, <h2>,
>   <h3>, <h4>, <h5>, <h6>, <header>, <hr>, <menu>, <nav>,` **`<ol>`**`, <pre>,
>   <section>, <table>, <ul>` or another `<p>` element, or if there is no
>   more content in the parent element and the parent element is not an
>    element. ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p))

The use of the `<ol>` tag immediately after/inside the `<p>` tag closes the `<p>`. In your case, this means the `<p>` tag has no content. Take a look at the snippet below, I have the two `ol`s in a `p` and alternatively in a `div` then I select the parents with plain javascript and log their inner html:

```js
var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0]

console.log("p:", p.innerHTML);

var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0]

console.log("div:", div.innerHTML);
```

```html
<p> 
    <ol id="First list">
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>bar</li>
    </ol>
    <ol id="Second list">
        <li>baz</li>
    </ol>
</p>

<div>
    <ol id="First list">
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>bar</li>
    </ol>
    <ol id="Second list">
        <li>baz</li>
    </ol>
</div>



<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

So, if you place the `ol`s in a `div`, you should be able to get this to work:

```html
<div>
    <ol id="First list">
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>bar</li>
    </ol>
    <ol id="Second list">
        <li>baz</li>
    </ol>
</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    sel = d3.select("div").selectAll("ol")

    console.log("number of elements in selection: ", sel.size())
</script>
```

Comment: the closing tag `</p>` would then be illegal HTML, the `<p>` is already implicitly closed.

Comment: @rioV8, Yep (I was going to add it to the answer originally, but skipped it as the solution should avoid that issue altogether) , though how browsers deal with that might offer some variety - I was a bit surprised in with firefox (the only one I checked for the answer), it inserted an open `<p>` just before the `</p>`.

Comment: If only browsers had rejected illegal HTML from the very first one we would have had a lot less problems. And an easier task for the HTML parser coder to try and fix the stuff presented.